# Is it true that $P_Y(y)=\int_{\mathcal{X}} P_{Y|X}(y|t) f_X(t) dt$ for mixed probability distributions?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, joint-distribution

Suppose $Y,X$ are two continuous random variables, with supports $\mathcal{Y}$ and $\mathcal{X}$ respectively. Let $f_Y$ be the pdf of $Y$ and $f_{Y|X}$ be the pdf of $Y$ given $X$.

We know that, for each $y\in \mathcal{Y}$,
$$
f_Y(y)=\int_{\mathcal{X}} \underbrace{f_{Y|X}(y|t) f_X(t)}_{\text{joint pdf of $Y,X$}} dt
$$

Now, suppose that $Y$ is a discrete random variable. So, $\mathcal{Y}$ is a finite set. Hence, we have a probability mass function for $Y$, denoted by $P_Y$. Further, we denote by $P_{Y|X}$ the probability mass function of $Y$ conditional on $X$. Is it still true that
$$
P_Y(y)=\int_{\mathcal{X}} \underbrace{P_{Y|X}(y|t) f_X(t)}_{\text{mixed joint density of $Y,X$ ?}} dt \quad?
$$

Comment: Yes, it is. Personally I would write $P(Y=y)=\int_{\mathcal X}P(Y=y\mid X=x)f_X(x)dx$.

Comment: You need to take the integral with respect to x, not t. For a better understanding/formal proof you could look at the law of total probability and, possibly, the law of total expectation:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation

Comment: @Baraliuh I would choose for $x$ too but that is not a necessity. This because it concerns a bound variable so that $\int h(x)dx=\int h(t)dt$.

Comment: @drhab Aaah. Yeah, that is my bad, I did not notice that OP used $f_X(t)$ rather than $f_X(x)$.